# A function to import javascript after the page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, import, onload

I'm working on a Electron project called WebOSv3. This project contains a lot of javascript files, such as windowLogic, generalLogic, and a whole lot more. About twenty of them at this moment.

The important one here though is onloadLogic. This file contains the `onload = function() {}`. I want to be able to load all of the other javascript files from the onload function. But, a function like this ...

```js
function loadJS(file) {
    (async () => { import(file); })();
}
```

doesn't work after the page has been loaded. Is there any way to import Javascript after the page is loaded?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

TechWorldInc

---

**EDIT**:

Say there is a function called `setWindowControls()` in a file called `/System/js/windowLogic.js`.
If I execute the function above to load `/System/js/windowLogic.js`, I still can't execute `setWindowControls()`.

**EDIT 2**:
Here is a more complete example of my problem:

```js
//onloadLogic//

onload = function () {
    loadJS("./System/js/windowLogic.js")
}

function loadJS(file) {
    (async () => { import(file); })();
}

//./System/js/windowLogic.js//

function setWindowControls() {
    var x = document.getElementById("window");
    // . . . //
}

//Javascript console//
//
// > setWindowControls();
// < Uncaught ReferenceError: setWindowControls is not defined
//      at <anonymous>: 1: 1
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? In what way? Can you edit your question with the *desired behaviour* and the *actual behaviour*.

Comment: The behavior I want to have is me just being able to say `loadJS("/path/to/file.js");` anywhere in my code and then having the code inside of the loaded file being effective immediately.

Comment: You've not answered my question. Loading JavaScript files can do two things, it can have "side effects" (You load the file immediately something happens), or it can make functions  and objects available to the module that loads it. I'm assuming you want the former.

Also, what you haven't done is actually explained *what happens* when you execute the code you included in your question.

Comment: The thing that happens, @BenWainwright, is nothing. The code in the loaded file isn't accessible and nothing else happens. Okay. Let me make it a little more clear. Say there is a function called `setWindowControls()` in a file called `/System/js/windowLogic.js`. If I execute the function in the first question to load `/System/js/windowLogic.js`, I still can't execute `setWindowControls()`.

Comment: Can you include a minimal but complete example of you trying to do all the above, including the error messages you get

Comment: Following thread might help.

https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports